# read a specific sms when an event of incoming message in intel xdk? any suggestions?

Tags: intel-xdk

I'am developing an application that can send sms message and received the response to the application itself. I am using intel xdk as a platform to develop this application...

Answer (score 1):

Most SMS plugins only offers sending, but there are few with sending and receiving.

This one might work.
http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.rjfun.cordova.sms

As claimed in the plugin README, it offers quite rich APIs:

Methods

```
sendSMS(address(s), text, successCallback, failureCallback);
listSMS(filter, successCallback, failureCallback);
deleteSMS(filter, successCallback, failureCallback);

startWatch(successCallback, failureCallback);
stopWatch(successCallback, failureCallback);

enableIntercept(on_off, successCallback, failureCallback);
restoreSMS(msg_or_msgs, successCallback, failureCallback);
```

Events

```
'onSMSArrive'
```

And, there is a single page demo, you may have a look.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "received the response to the application itself".  If you mean that incoming SMS messages are processed by your app, than you might look into a plugin like this:

https://github.com/asanka-x/Phonegap-SMS

I haven't tried it, but it claims to be able to send and receive SMS messages.  You may also need to set up your phone so that this app handles incoming SMS messages.  And it only works on Android.

`intel.xdk.device.sendSMS` can be used to send messages, but doesn't supply a way to receive them.  So if you mean that there's some other mechanism by which the response is handled, maybe that's enough for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: do you know any tutorial or something a manual to use the plugin in github you suggested >> https://github.com/asanka-x/Phonegap-SMS <<

Comment: I've not used either of them myself, but here's a different one that has an example in the doc on the main github page - https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin

Comment: thanks for the reply much help for my project development, but do you know any example for fetching the incoming message because the example that in - github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin - is just sending sms...

Comment: Do you know any site that can have an example usage of this codes?   isSupported

smsplugin.isSupported(successCallback(result),failureCallback(error));
startReception

smsplugin.startReception(successCallback(result),failureCallback(error));